# CollectionView cell reuse

Tags: ios, swift

I am using collection View and loading more data through API call. When I am loading more data from API, collectionView showing activity indicator at bottom but unable to add more collectionView cell just updating the existing cells only.

Any help will be appreciated.

For reference

```
// MARK: Delegates
extension ProdSubCat: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == subCatArr.count - 1 && !self.isLoading {
            loadMoreData()
        }
    }

For load more data
======================

func loadMoreData() {

        if !self.isLoading {
            self.isLoading = true
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                // Fake background loading task for 2 seconds
                sleep(2)
                // Download more data here
                self.productSubCategories(offset: self.offsetValue, limit: 25)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    self.isLoading = false
                }
            }
        }
    }

 API CALL Method:
======================
 // MARK: API
    func productSubCategories(offset: Int, limit: Int) {


if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
                    let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)
                    print(swiftyJsonVar["message"].string ?? "")
                    if let category = swiftyJsonVar["product"].arrayObject {
                        if category.count != 0 {
                            self.subCatArr = category as! [[String : Any]]
                        } else {
                            self.isLoading = true
                        }
                    }
                    self.offsetValue = self.offsetValue + limit
                    print(self.offsetValue)
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                } else {
                    print("\(String(describing: response.request))")
                    print("Error")
                }
                ProgressHUD.dismiss()
            }
        } else {
            self.alertMessage(title: "Connectivity Error!", message: "Please connect to internet")
            ProgressHUD.dismiss()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are the other dataSource methods (`numberOfItems` and `cellForItem`)? The problem could be there, you have to add new models to the data source array and then reload the collection view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing your current data source value with new value i.e

```
self.subCatArr = category as! [[String : Any]]
```

Instead, you need to append the data to current array.

```
if let category = swiftyJsonVar["product"].arrayObject {
   if category.count != 0 {
      for obj in category { 
        self.subCatArray.append(obj)
      }
    } else {
            self.isLoading = true
      }
}
```